# Iterating over a list of dataframes in a function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've got a dataset with more than 4000 rows which correspond to sunlight hours all along the year.

I've sliced this dataframe in a list by month so I have several hours of sunlight in a list of 12 dataframes. Here's a sample.

```
      index   YYYY  MM  DD     H  DOY      ANGLE      AZIMUTH        
        812   2020   3  21   6.0   81   0.570550    89.931404  
        813   2020   3  21   7.0   81  11.781984    99.975618  
        814   2020   3  21   8.0   81  22.634332   110.842581  
        815   2020   3  21   9.0   81  32.658711   123.478690  
        816   2020   3  21  10.0   81  41.147775   139.003890
```

So I have a list which nest twelve dataframe like this one.

Now I want to iterate by month in a function that calculates the shadow projections.

First step, define my month function:

```
def month(n_month):
        df_month = df.loc[df['MM'] == n_month]
        return df_month
```

Second step store months in a list:

```
month_list = []
    for i in range(1, 13):
        month_list.append(month(i))
```

Third step, iterate `month_list` over a predefined fuction:
This function consists in assigning an azimut and an elevation angle for each sunlight hour of every month:

```
def shade_array (index):
        azimut = df.AZIMUT[index]
        altitude = df.ANGLE[index]
        shade = hillshade_beta(elevation, azimuth = azimut, altitude = altitude)
        return shade
```

The output is an array.

And here is where I get stuck, when trying to iterate this function over evary dataframe in the month list and store the arrays in a new list:

```
array_list = []

for i in month_list:
    array_list.append(shade_array(i))
```

This yields the following error message:

`TypeError: Indexing a Series with DataFrame is not supported, use the appropriate DataFrame column`

Is it possible to iterate a list of dataframes?

The expected output is a list of twelve array lists, each array nested in this second order lists belong to the values of shadow per pixel in a raster.

Comment: kindly post an expected output. by the way, it is possible to iterate a list of dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for month splits and then build list of arrays with a list comprehension where intermediate object, `month_list`, is not needed. Your main issue is in the `shade_array()` method where index *is* the data frame. So instead of `df.AZIMUT[index]` it should be `index.AZIMUT` or more clearly use `df` as parameter:

```
def shade_array(df):
   azimut = df['AZIMUT']
   altitude = df['ANGLE']
   shade = hillshade_beta(elevation, azimuth = azimut, altitude = altitude)
   return shade

shade_arrays = [shade_array(g) for i, g in df.groupby(['MM'])]
```

Even better, run a dictionary comprehension for months as indexes:

```
import calendar

shade_arrays = {calendar.month_name[i]:shade_array(g) for i, g in df.groupby(['MM'])}

shade_arrays['January']
shade_arrays['February']
shade_arrays['March']
...
```

Comment: I've tested it and yields this error message:
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: Does `hillside_beta` expect scalar values or series for *azimuth* and *altitude* params? Please show its library or definition.